# PHP variable in side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to combine a PHP variable and JavaScript to get at the **"the_link_to_the_page_I_want"**.

```
window.onload = function openWindow()
      {
        window.open('the_link_to_the_page_I_want', 'newwindow', config='height=100, width=400, '
            + 'toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, '
            + 'directories=no, status=no');
      };
```

I tried to write the path like below and that does not work. While I'm aware that PHP and JS work in backend and front end respectively, is this possible to achieve? Do you have a suggestion?

```
'../uploads/"<?php echo $wec; ?>"'
```

The complete snippet would look like this:

```
      window.onload = function openWindow()
  {
    window.open('../uploads/"<?php echo $myPHPvariable; ?>"', 'newwindow', config='height=100, width=400, '
        + 'toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, '
        + 'directories=no, status=no');
  };
```

PS: I'm using the PHP variable to reach a specific file inside the ***uploads*** folder basis a user input.

Comment: can the down voter add a comment?

Comment: You're using wrong quotes, code highlight show you where.

Comment: What happens currently when you execute the code?

Comment: @u_mulder Thank you, I see now where the issue is. you're right and it's the way I have used the quotes burned my time!

Comment: @chris85 It was showing a window opened upto the point of the uplaods folder and not the specific file I wanted to open.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `json_encode` to ensure that the string is a valid JS string.

```
window.onload = function openWindow(){       {
    window.open(<?php echo json_encode( '../uploads/' . $myPHPvariable);?>, 'newwindow', config='height=100, width=400, '
        + 'toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, '
        + 'directories=no, status=no');
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it will work. First of all is file have extension ".php". It must be a php file and second you have a error in code.
No need of double quotes. it should be like this

```
window.open('../uploads/<?php echo $myPHPvariable; ?>',...
```